# can I use same method in different child controllers in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, parent

I want run a function in a particular child controller. Same function name is present in all the child controller. my query is how to I call the function from  particular controller

**parent controller:**

```
app.controller("parentctrl",function($scope){
$scope.clickfunc = function(){
 $scope.childmethod();
}
});
```

**child controllers:**

```
app.controller("childctrlone",function($scope){
$scope.childmethod= function(){
 alert(1);
}
});
app.controller("childctrltwo",function($scope){
$scope.childmethod= function(){
 alert(2);
}
});
```

I want to call $scope.childmethod() from childctrltwo

Comment: There is no direct way to do that. Is there a logic determine which child to call?

Comment: if so, you could trigger event from your parent controller's `clickfunc` and you will listen to these events in each of the child controllers. And depending on data emitted by your parent controller, your child controller will determine whether to run it's function or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can do this by broadcasting an event from parent and listening to this event in child controllers.(Recommended)**

```
app.controller("parentctrl",function($scope){
$scope.clickfunc = function(){
 $scope.$broadcast("callChildMethod",{child : 1});//1 if you want to call 1st child method or 2 if you want to call second child method
}
});
app.controller("childctrlone",function($scope){
$scope.childmethod= function(){
 alert(1);
}
$scope.$on("callChildMethod",function(event,args){
if(args.child == 1) $scope.childMethod()
})
});
app.controller("childctrltwo",function($scope){
$scope.childmethod= function(){
 alert(2);
}
$scope.$on("callChildMethod",function(event,args){
if(args.child == 2) $scope.childMethod()
})
});
```

**Other ways(but not recommended)**-

**Using $$childHead or $$childTail-**

```
// will only work if app controller has only two childs in order
 app.controller("parentctrl",function($scope){
    $scope.clickfunc = function(){
      $scope.$$childHead.childMethod();// first child
      $scope.$$childHead.$$nextSibling.childMethod(); // second child
      $scope.$$childTail.childMethod()// second child
      $scope.$$childTail.$$previousSibling.childMethod()//first child
    }
 });
```

**Using angular.element()**

```
 app.controller("parentctrl",function($scope){
    $scope.clickfunc = function(){
      angular.element("#idofFirstChild").scope().childMethod();// first child
      angular.element("#idofSecondChild").scope().childMethod(); // second child
    }
 });
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. is there any way to identify the controller rather than {child : 1} something by its controller name

Comment: Not possible by controller name but I have included two more ways. If you like my answer kindly upvote